# Click on element in robot framework is not working in IE and work fine in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer, robotframework

Click Element is not working in *Robot Framework*, in the `log.html` it shows that it clicked on the element, but it does not actually happen in the browser.

The element which I want to click is:

```
<a href="http://www.twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Orange%20named%20a%20Top%20Employer%20Global%202018%20for%203rd%20consecutive%20year&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fintegration-ruby.proj.620nm.com%2Fen%2Fblogs%2Forange-named-top-employer-global-2018-3rd-consecutive-year&amp;via=orangebusiness" class="share-button-twitter" target="_blank" title="Share on twitter">
        <span class="fa-lg fa-stack text_black"> <i class="fa fa-circle-thin fa-stack-2x"></i> <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-stack-1x"></i> </span>
    </a>
```

I run my test using:

```
Execute JavaScript    document.querySelector(".share-button-twitter").click()
Execute JavaScript    document.querySelector('a[title="Share on twitter"]').click()
Execute JavaScript    document.querySelector(".fa-lg fa-stack text_black").click()
Click Link  //a[@title="Share on twitter"]
Click Element    //i[@class="fa fa-twitter fa-stack-1x"]
Click Element    //span[@class="fa-lg fa-stack text_black"]
```

The element is visible in the page, and the script works fine in *Chrome* and *Firefox* I find this issue with the browser *IE*.

What can be the reason for this? Any idea to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Update your Internet Explorer to the latest version. And also download the appropriate supported version of IEDriver for that version of IE. The problem is only here, and no where else.

Comment: To resolve the probleme , i add FEATURE_BFCACHE  in the registry and i create a DWORD value named iexplore.exe with the value of 0.    For 32-bit Windows: The key you must examine in the registry editor is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE.